# Update records only when ID matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

How would I update data in a table in a separate database based on the records in the current database?

For instance I want to update the field "status" in the database called "database_old" with the value contained in the database "database_new" . My current data exists in the database "database_new". I want to only update records in the "database_old" db when the record_id field matches.  The fields "status" and "record_id" exists in the table "products" in both databases.  As as I said the field "status" should be updated with the value from the "database_new" but only update if the record_id matches.

This a MS SQL 2005 database.

Comment: Are both databases on the same SQL Server instance?  Plausible to be on difference instances on the same server, but more likely to be different instances on different servers...

Comment: both db's are on the same server

Comment: @Jeff: You can have multiple SQL Server instances installed on the server.  Just saying

Comment: both db's are on the same server and the same instance of SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both database are on the same server just use the 3 part name  Database.dbo.TableName.  Example:

```
update old
set old.status = new.status
from database_old.dbo.products old
inner join database_new.dbo.products new
on old.record_id = new.record_id
```

If they are on different servers then you need to have a linked server and then use a 4 part name.

Answer (score 3):

```
update database_old.dbo.products
set status = new.status
from database_new.dbo.products new
where database_old.dbo.products.record_id = new.products.record_id
```

Comment: +1. Remember this needs linked servers to work on different DB instances